# How can I have a function that returns different types in F#?

Tags: f#, lexical-analysis

I've made a scanner in F#.  Currently it returns a list of bunch of tuples with type (Token, string).

Ideally I'd like to return a list of tuples that might contain different types.  For example:

```
(Token, string) 
//if it's an identifier

(Token, float)
//if it's a float. 

(Token, int)
//etc
```

So, Basically I'd like to return type `(Token, _)`  but I'm not sure how to specify this.  Right now it just has errors complaining of mismatched types.  I'm looking through my book, and wikibooks, but I'm not really sure what this is called.

If this really isn't possible, I guess I can convert the types later on, but I was hoping I could just return stuff this way.

Comment: Can you show a sample input and desired output for your function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two relatively easy ways to handle this in F#.  One would be to create a discriminated union:

```
type Expression =
| Identifier of string
| FloatValue of float
| IntValue of int
| ...
```

and then define your function so that it returns a `(Token * Expression) list`.  The other possibility is to box everything into an object and then return a `(Token * obj) list`.  This is slightly easier for the producer of the list, but much more annoying for the consumer.

Comment: Ok, syntax question.  I tried doing this:
let (Token * Expression) functionName = ....
and 
(Token * Expression) functionName = ....

to try to specify the return type but it complains about both.  I'm just trying to specify the return type here,

Comment: @jeff: In F#, you assign types to let-bound expressions using `let expression : type = ...`.  In your case this might look something like `let functionName : string -> Token * Expression = fun input -> ...` or `let functionName (input : string) : Token * Expression = ...`.  However, in most cases F# will be able to infer the types for you and you don't need to declare them.

Comment: Ok so i tried something similar to this:
let functionName (txt: string) : Token * Expression = 
...codes...
(<Token> , <string>) 

in VS2010, it underlines the string and says "This expression was expected to have type Expression but here has type string"

I definitely included string in the definition of Expression as shown in your original reply:
type Expression =
...
| strVal of string

Comment: @jeff: you have to use the constructor within the function rather than just returning the string.  That is, if you are trying to return a string value `s`, you should be returning `strVal s` instead, so that the returned value has type `Expression` rather than `string`.

Comment: awesome, you are a life saver!

Answer (score 4):

I think that using discriminated union as kvb suggests is the way to go. Just to add some more information, when writing scanners in F#, it is common to define a token type `Token` that lists various types of tokens that may carry additional information like this:

```
type Token = 
// Some toknes with no additional information
| LParen | RParen | Begin | End
// Some tokens with additional values
| Identifier of string
| IntValue of int
| ...
```

Then you completely remove the need for representing the value separately from the token and you can work with just `Token list`.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to previous answers, look at the Choice types (and Choice cases such as Choice1of3 etc.).