# F# polymorphic function

Tags: f#

Suppose I have 2 record types

```
type A = { a: string; parameters: parameter list }
type B = { b: string; parameters: parameter list }
```

where
    type parameter = { name: string; value : string }

How can I write function `parameter`

```
let parameter name value entity = 
     { entity with parameters = List.append 
                                    parameters 
                                    [ { name = name; value = value; } ]
     }
```

Such as

```
let a =  { a = "a", parameters = [] } |> parameter "p", "v" // a is a record of type A
let b =  { b = "b", parameters = [] } |> parameter "p", "v" // b is record of type B
```

Comment: This is a dupe.  Standard solution is to wrap A and B with a DU

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986461/how-can-i-have-a-function-that-returns-different-types-in-f

Comment: Inside `parameter` do you only access `parameters` or do you need `a` and `b` as well?

Comment: You can implement the function like this: `let parameter name value entity = entity`. This meets the requirements, but is probably not what you want. What is it that you really want to do?

Comment: @MarkSeemann

Sorry, should have made it clearer:

    let parameter name value entity = 
         { entity with parameters = List.append parameters [ { name = name; value = value; } ]

Comment: @JohnPalmer A and B are not related (besides having parameter list), I am not sure I can have them in one DU. For example, A and C might have a options list (similar to parameters), so A will have parameters and options, B will have just parameters and C will have just options

Comment: @CaringDev Sorry, I've updated my question

Comment: What is the type of the expression `{ name = name; value = value; }`?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I've updated code in question.

Comment: @mbergal See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038317/generic-method-on-record/35041429#35041429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not idiomatic F#, but this can be done using SRTP. I assume you have simplified the use-case for StackOverflow, but if `A` and `B` are really not related types, then I think you should revisit your overall program design.

I defined a `Parameter` type as this:

```ml
type Parameter =
  {
    Name : string
    Value : string
  }
```

Now, we need to add a method to types `A` and `B` that implement the addition of a parameter:

```ml
type A =
  {
    A : string
    Parameters : Parameter list
  }
  with
    member this.AddParameter(p : Parameter) =
      {
        this with
          Parameters =
            p :: this.Parameters
      }
```

And...

```ml
type B =
  {
    B : string
    Parameters : Parameter list
  }
  with
    member this.AddParameter(p : Parameter) =
      {
        this with
          Parameters =
            p :: this.Parameters
      }
```

Then we can write an `inline` function that calls this method:

```ml
let inline addParameter (p : Parameter) (x : ^t) : ^t =
  (^t : (member AddParameter : Parameter -> ^t) (x, p))
```

Here `^t` will be replaced with `A` or `B` (or whatever) depending on the call-site. The syntax for SRTP isn't great, but it is [better in F# 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-fsharp-7/#making-working-with-srtps-easier).

Usage:

```ml
let p = { Name = "p"; Value = "abc" }

let a : A = 
  { A = "a"; Parameters = [] } 
  |> addParameter p

printfn $"%A{a}"

let b : B = 
  { B = "b"; Parameters = [] } 
  |> addParameter p

printfn $"%A{b}"
```